# How to display list in DataTable

Tags: list, collections, datatable

I desperately need to create a dataTable in jsf with the following dynamic string data. I've gone as far as I can and I desperately need help. What I want to do isto loop through the data to show on my dataTable.

The following is how far I've come

```
enter code here
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author mySelf
 */
public class One {

    static String s = "1701|001271651913|e13f7108-6f7c-4ea5-b77f-f016259a574e, "
            + "1701|001207488366|2ee40509-af86-4470-84c8-0d2aec494367";

    public static List<String> myGuava() {
        List<String> ss = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));
        List<String> oldList = new ArrayList<>(ss);

        Iterator<String> iterator = oldList.iterator();

        List myList = new ArrayList();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ArrayList as = new ArrayList();
            as.add(iterator.next().replace("|", ",").trim());
            Collections.addAll(myList, as);
        }
        return myList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> myGuava = One.myGuava();

        System.out.println(myGuava);
    }
}
```

Any help that will help me display this on jsf dataTable will be very much valued.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Do you have a particular "data table" implementation in mind?

If not, why not take a look at some of the JSF components on [RichFaces](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataGrid.jsf?c=dataGrid)?

ALSO: This tutorial might help:

- http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/

It uses [JSF Facelets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/facelets-454361.html)

'Hope that helps!